# netsuite - How to change column field of standard Inventory transaction

Tags: transactions, customization, netsuite

I created a custom transaction column field with id custcol_tl_expectedshipdate for 'Expected Ship Date' column for the page Transactions -> Inventory -> Reallocate Items. So the question is how do I edit the standard screen with my custom transaction column field?

I can't seem to find Inventory anywhere in the Customization Manager. Please help

[So this is how the standard screen looks like, and what I want is to replace the 'Expected Ship Date' with my own custom transaction field?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Kaq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a page in NetSuite that cannot be customized.

Comment: I see. I think I should create a custom page for Reallocate Items but I don't know how to. Is this possible using suiteScript?

Comment: There is no option to create custom page.